# Django/DRF wide validation

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

This is more of a conceptual question. I am not looking for code sample answers. Simply an insight into validation when working with Django and DRF.

Consider the following the model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField()
    products = JsonField(default='[]')
    regexp = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I am using Django REST Framework and I have a serializer which serializes this model for a `StoreView`.

I have some validation I would like to enforce. For example, I want `products` to take the form: `{"id":x, "optional-title":y}` and I would like to enforce some regex validation for `regexp`.

How would I enforce validation for this model in one single place and still get correct error returns. By 'correct error returns', I mean that I should return a `400 BAD REQUEST` when I receive some bad payload in from an `API` client but I should also return a normal Django `ValidationError` if I create an object on the model level.

I can't see the advantage of serializer level validation. It appears to me that I would just need to duplicate my validations in the model level if I want to guarantee that a bad object never gets into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `validate_<field>` method within serializer class

```
def validate_regexp(obj,regex):
    #your regex validation goes here
    #valid_regex = .....
    if not valid_regex:
          raise serializers.ValidationError("Regex invalid")

    return regex
```

Comment: This does not address the question at all. Please read again.